# Rails - React components doesn't get mounted on second page load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker

I'm using `Rails` with `webpacker` with `react`.

I'm loading my components like this in my view file:

```
<div id="mycomponent"></div>
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'components/mycomponent' %>
```

In `mycomponent`, I have:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <MyComponent />,
    document.getElementById('mycomponent'),
  )
})
```

So on initial page load, `mycomponent` is mounted.
But when I visit another page, hit back or click on a link to the dashboard (in this case), the component doesn't load. Had to hit refresh to load it.

I think it has something to do with some caching techinques that `Rails` is using?
How do I get the components to load on every request

Comment: Why do you need this? `DOMContentLoaded`

Comment: To mount the component on `DOMContentLoaded`.

Comment: Yea but won't need that as you are executing js after the container element

Comment: You're right. It mounts every time now But why wouldn't it work in `DOMContentLoaded` event? I think I got that code from [webpacker](https://github.com/rails/webpacker#react-1) and thought its best practice.

Comment: It's not required. And am not sure why it was not working for you but that piece is not required. Are you having ajax navigation on your page?

Comment: No ajax. Just a normal link output with `link_to`. Well, at least its working now :)

Comment: Great :) I've use react with Rails but with a custom setup so ain't sure why yours was not working :)

Comment: I realise my `url` wasn't changing in inspector. Some how `turbolink` came to mind and my pages are not *ajaxified* anymore after removing it from the app :)

Comment: So my assumption was correct that the pages were ajaxified and hence, your domcontentloaded never fired again :)

Comment: Yep, exactly :)

Answer (score 0):

So [turbolinks](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks) was doing some optimizations behind.

Realized that the `url` in chrome inspector remained the same when I changed pages.

Pages were loading *fully* after removing `//= require turbolinks` from `app/assets/javascript/application.js`.

Seen some people pointing to [jquery.turbolinks](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks) for `onload` issues with `turbolink`. Not tested though.